# Which one is the action force and which one is the reaction force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Suppose a body lies on a table. So, which object here applies the normal contact force, and henceforth, on which object is the reaction force applied?

Since every action has a reaction, I want to know which object here first exerts the action, so as to get reaction in terms of normal contact force?

Comment: There is no "first". They are both present at the same time.

Comment: @Steeven That should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no "first". They are both present at the same time.

Saying "action and reaction" is just a way of speech. A way to point out that force always comes in pairs. But one is not more "action" than the other.

Comment: Would these action-reaction pairs be equal in magnitude?

Comment: @SachinChaudhary Yea, yes! We only talk about action/reaction pairs because of Newton's 3rd law. That law says that there to any force will always be an equal but opposite reaction force

Answer (score 0):

The body on the table is exerting a force on the table, and the table is exerting an equal an opposite force on the body.  This is called an "action-reaction pair."  If I call the force that the body exerts on the table the action force, then the force that the table exerts on the body is the corresponding reaction force.  If I call the force that the table exerts on the body as the action force, then the force that the body exerts on the table is the corresponding reaction force.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter which force you will call action, because they are acting at same time but on different objects.if you call one force action then other one would be automatically reaction.I think Steevan have given a correct explaination.